# Bibliography and Index \label for cross-reference

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, indexing

I have each chapter of my `book` class in a different file all linked up in a master file. I also have bibliography in `refs.bib` file and also have an index. I'm trying to create a cross-reference to the Bibliography and Index special chapters of the book.

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\renewcommand\bibname{References}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{./tex/refs}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\printindex
```

In my introduction, I would like to say to summarise my content where I say, "Chapter 1 descibes so and so, Chapter 2 .. etc. The end of the book also contains the list of references  which you can link to by clicking on the numbers in the square brackets. An Index  is contained at the very end of the book to make finding concepts and key words easy by clicking on the concept, which shoudl take you to the place in the book it is described in."

I have struggled to find a way to provide cross-reference links to both Bibliography and Index. I know how to use the `\label` command and have no problem with it. But I don't know where or how to put a `\label` command in the above mentioned special chapters.

I've tried labels like so:

```
\bibliography{./tex/refs}\label{cha:refs}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}\label{cha:index}
```

but that seems to have put the wrong reference number - the number of the conclusion chapter was displayed for both links, but each one actually correctly taken me to each pseudo chapter!

Can anyone advise

1. if this is the correct way of doing it
2. if it is, how can I display either proper numbers or ideally show References and Index as links themselves so I don't confuse the reader by giving numbers to the chapters that don't have numbers in the TOC?

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution is to use the facilities provided by `etoolbox` to patch the `\bibliography` and `\printindex` commands. Using `hyperref` you can use something like:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\list}{\label{bib}\list}{}{}
\appto{\theindex}{\phantomsection\label{idx}}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
Test: \hyperref[bib]{bibliography} starting at page \pageref{bib}, and 
\hyperref[idx]{Index} starting at page \pageref{idx}

test\index{test}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{<bibstyle>}
\bibliography{<bibfile(s)>}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Although the etoolbox part of this didn't quite work for me, but what I really took away is \hyperref[bib]{bibliography} part. Because the links already work in my solution properly, it was the numbers that were wrong. So now everything works. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

For me It worked well by just using `\hyperref` directly with the `\addcontentsline`. For example I want to add  **Introduction** into the table of contents, we can just do this : `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\hyperref[chap:Introduction]{Introduction}}`. `chap:Introduction` is the label name for specific chapter and `Introduction` is the custom label.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\label{chap:Introduction}

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\hyperref[chap:Introduction]{Introduction}}

\end{document}
```