# How can I link to the bibliography chapter within the text of a document with \ref?

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, cross-referencing, tocbibind

I have a project which has a bibliography which I have included into my table of contents using `tocbibind`. In my report I have a section which details the structure of the report, I mention each chapter within but I can't reference the bibliography as the link goes to the previous section. See example code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{first chapter}\label{chap:one}
first we have \ref{chap:one} then \ref{chap:two} followed by \ref{chap:bib}

\chapter{second chapter}\label{chap:two}

\bibliography{references}{}\label{chap:bib}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}

\end{document}
```

The `\ref{chap:bib}` points to chapter two since bibliography is not a real chapter, how do I link to it or reference it in text?

Comment: you could try it using a `\phantomsection`

Comment: @Rico, thanks, will this increase the number of future chapters? I neglected to mention I have an appendix afterwards that has many sections that I also link to. question has been edited to reflect this.

Comment: to be honest, this just popped in my mind, I did not give it a try so you need to try it first :)

Comment: See also [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78099)

Comment: MWE compiles fine but gives incorrect linking, thanks henrique, that is another solution to the problem. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `\bibliography` results in reading a file that contains

```
\begin{thebibliography}{<number>}
<contents>
\end{bibliography}
```

and the `\chapter` command appears inside the group enclosing the environment, setting `\label` after `\bibliography{references}` has no effect, because the value of `\@currentlabel` has been forgotten and you get the previous one (in the example the one relative to chapter two).

However, the option `numbib` to `tocbibind` executes

```
\chapter{\tocbibname}
```

so we have just to add `\label{chap:bib}` to the macro `\tocbibname`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto{\tocbibname}{\label{chap:bib}}
%% or just \renewcommand{\tocbibname}{Bibliography\label{chap:bib}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{first chapter}\label{chap:one}
first we have \ref{chap:one} then \ref{chap:two} followed by \ref{chap:bib}

\chapter{second chapter}\label{chap:two}

\nocite{*}

\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\end{document}
```

This will work flawlessly also with `hyperref`.

Note that `{}` after `\bibliography{references}` is superfluous and that the style's name is `IEEEtran` (on case insensitive systems it could be equivalent, but not all systems are).

Comment: Perfect, thank you (oh and the ieeetran is linking to a specific file as the default wasn't working on my system, thanks for noticing though.)