# Cross-reference Bibliography itself with biblatex and memoir?

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, cross-referencing, memoir, cleveref

Is it possible to insert a cross-reference link to the Bibliography itself — not just to individual items in the Bibliography — with `biblatex`, `hyperref`, and `cleverref` under the `memoir` class?

That is, as in the following source, what label could be created where and how, so that the `\cref{WHAT}` shown in the Preface would point to the Bibliography? (So that clicking that link would take one to the Bibliography's first page.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hyperindex,colorlinks, citecolor=red} 

\begin{filecontents}{biblatexdoc.bib}
@article{Archimedes200,author = {Archimedes},title = {Pi's the limit },
journal = {Syracuse J. Gastronom.\ Math.}, year = {200BCE},volume = {10},pages={\textsc{CCCXV}--\textsc{CCCXIV}}}

@article{EulerE1776,Author = {Euler, Leonhard},Title = {All about E},
Journal = {Math.\ Psychol.},Year = {1776},Volume = {4},pages={1--2718}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblatexdoc}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Prefarc}

The Bibliography (\cref{WHAT}) includes only works actually cited.

\chapter{Math}

Archimedes~\cite{Archimedes200} and Euler~\cite{EulerE1776} studied the constants, $\pi$ and $e$,  respectively.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

`\nameref{WHAT}` seems to be a better variant than `\cref{WHAT}`, the latter requires a label to a counter (well, `\nameref` does need this at well, but it is easier to fake the label with a wrapper, say, `\biblabel` which will use `\label` internally and automatically adds the hyperlink to the bibliography.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hyperindex,colorlinks, citecolor=red} 
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatexdoc.bib}
@article{Archimedes200,author = {Archimedes},title = {Pi's the limit },
journal = {Syracuse J. Gastronom.\ Math.}, year = {200BCE},volume = {10},pages={\textsc{CCCXV}--\textsc{CCCXIV}}}

@article{EulerE1776,Author = {Euler, Leonhard},Title = {All about E},
Journal = {Math.\ Psychol.},Year = {1776},Volume = {4},pages={1--2718}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblatexdoc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\biblabel}[1]{%
  \phantomsection
  \edef\@currentlabel{\bibname}%
  \edef\@currentlabelname{\bibname}% Provide the \nameref - anchor name
  \label{#1}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Preface}

The \nameref{WHAT} includes only works actually cited.

\chapter{Math}

Archimedes~\cite{Archimedes200} and Euler~\cite{EulerE1776} studied the constants, $\pi$ and $e$,  respectively.


\printbibliography\biblabel{WHAT}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

Support for more than one bibliography.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hyperindex,colorlinks, citecolor=red} 
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatexdoc.bib}
@article{Archimedes200,author = {Archimedes},title = {Pi's the limit },
journal = {Syracuse J. Gastronom.\ Math.}, year = {200BCE},volume = {10},pages={\textsc{CCCXV}--\textsc{CCCXIV}}}

@article{EulerE1776,Author = {Euler, Leonhard},Title = {All about E},
Journal = {Math.\ Psychol.},Year = {1776},Volume = {4},pages={1--2718}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblatexdoc}

\makeatletter
\define@key{blx@bib2}{title}{\gdef\blx@thetitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\biblabel}[1]{%
  \phantomsection
  \edef\@currentlabel{\bibname}%
  \@ifundefined{blx@thetitle}{%
    \edef\@currentlabelname{\bibname}%
  }{%
    \edef\@currentlabelname{\blx@thetitle}%
  }%
  \label{#1}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Preface}

The \nameref{WHAT} includes only works actually cited, however, there is another \nameref{WHATOTHER}.

\chapter{Math}

Archimedes~\cite{Archimedes200} and Euler~\cite{EulerE1776} studied the constants, $\pi$ and $e$,  respectively.

\printbibliography[title={My sophisticated bibliography}]\biblabel{WHAT}

\printbibliography[title=Bib2]\biblabel{WHATOTHER}

\end{document}
```

**Update for multi-page bibliographies**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hyperindex,colorlinks, citecolor=red} 

%\usepackage{msc}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatexdoc.bib}
@article{Archimedes200,author = {Archimedes},title = {Pi's the limit },
journal = {Syracuse J. Gastronom.\ Math.}, year = {200BCE},volume = {10},pages={\textsc{CCCXV}--\textsc{CCCXIV}}}

@article{EulerE1776,Author = {Euler, Leonhard},Title = {All about E},
Journal = {Math.\ Psychol.},Year = {1776},Volume = {4},pages={1--2718}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblatexdoc}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples}


\makeatletter
\define@key{blx@bib2}{title}{\gdef\blx@thetitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\biblabel}[1]{%
  \phantomsection
  \@ifundefined{blx@thetitle}{%
    \edef\@currentlabelname{\bibname}%
    \edef\@currentlabel{\bibname}%
  }{%
    \edef\@currentlabel{\blx@thetitle}%
    \edef\@currentlabelname{\blx@thetitle}%
  }%
  \label{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\biblabelnote}[1]{%
  \defbibnote{#1}{\biblabel{#1}}%
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Preface}

The \nameref{WHAT} includes only works actually cited, however, there is another \nameref{WHATOTHER}.

\chapter{Math}
\nocite{*}

Archimedes~\cite{Archimedes200} and Euler~\cite{EulerE1776} studied the constants, $\pi$ and $e$,  respectively.

\biblabelnote{WHAT}
\printbibliography[title={My sophisticated bibliography},prenote={WHAT}]

\biblabelnote{WHATOTHER}
\printbibliography[title=Bib2,prenote={WHATOTHER}]

\end{document}
```

Comment: With two bibligraphies (see my comment to @rotton's answer), and different labels after the `\printbibliography[keyword=...,title=...]` calls,  with just `\nameref` I get the same "Bibliography" hyperlink source text (in the Preface). But with `\hyperref[`*label-name*`]{`*bibtitle*`}` I get the correct name for the 2nd one whose title is not "Bibliography".

Comment: @murray: There was no indication that you would use two bibliographies...

Comment: @murray: I've updated for more than one bibliography. See the code at the end, please

Comment: @Christiab Hupfer: Following general rules & practices, I tried to present as *simple* an example of what I was trying to do. Obviously, I made it too simple; sorry for that!

Comment: The links in the preface take me to the 2nd page of each bibliography, not the first. ???

Comment: @murray: Not for me. However, there is no 2nd page of each bibliography since your bibliography is very short

Comment: @murray: Next version, but since you're using `memoir` which does not fit really well with `biblatex` and disables `\prebibhook` etc. commands, I have to bypass this with `\biblabelnote` and `prenote`.

Comment: Alas, I already begin my 2nd bibliography with some text that is inserted by `\printbibliography[...,prenote=readnote]` after `\defbibnote{readprenote}{A couple sentences of text go here.}` So how can I handle the `prenote={WHATOTHER}` that's required?

Comment: @murray: Well, I showed you multiple options, each time after that you come with some more information of your real setup, that's salami slicing actually and **not** helpful. I posted 3 possible solutions that work for me in a normal setup which can't know about your settings since the given file by you does not reveal your 'obscure' setup.

Comment: What's wrong with doing the following, without `\biblabel` or`biblabelnote`: for the 1st bibliography, just `\printbibliography[...title=...,prenote=bibprenote]` after `\defbibnote{bibprenote}{\label{WHAT}}`; and for the 2nd, `\printbibliography[...,title=...,prenote=otherprenote]` after `\defbibnote{otherprenote}{\label{WHATOTHER}A couple of sentences of text go here.}` Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility (though not very sophisticated; partially taken [from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78084/bibliography-and-index-label-for-cross-reference)): Place the `\label` beneath `\printbibliography`.
In the chapter Preface write:

```
The \hyperref[WHAT]{Bibliography} includes only works actually cited.
```

Comment: While the patch shown at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78084/bibliography-and-index-label-for-cross-reference and your suggested `\hyperref` does work for the simple `memoir` plus `biblatex`document in my post, I don't see how to accomplish the same thing in my real-world document, which has two different bibliographies (generated via 2 different `.bib` resource files and different keywords for each that are then used as `keyword` options in the `\printbibliography` calls.